# Doctrine 2 DBAL returns only string datatypes

Tags: doctrine-orm, silex, dbal

I'm building a simple REST backend using Silex micro-framework.

Inside each controller, I'm running some query against MySQL database (using Doctrine 2 DBAL API), like the follow:

```
$app->get('/customers', function (Application $app) {
    $recordset = $app['db']->fetchAll('SELECT id, name FROM Customers');
    return $app->json($recordset);
});
```

Can anybody explain to me why Doctrine DBAL returns only `string` datatype, regardless column definitions? Below is the corresponding output using PHP `var_dump($recordset)` function (note that `id` field should be of type integer, not string):

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(5) "10043"
    ["name"]=>
    string(20) "Hey, I'm just a test"
  }
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: As the DBAL used PDO internally, I believe this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197005/how-to-get-numeric-types-from-mysql-using-pdo

Comment: @Maerlyn - I'm aware of the PDO problem but, looking into Doctrine source, I noticed that each database table column is mapped to the respective DBAL Type, which exposes the methods `convertToDatabaseValue` and `convertToPHPValue`. However these methods do not seem to affect the results of the query. Why?

Comment: I don't know the internals of doctrine, you may open a ticket on the doctrine repository on github to get an in-depth answer (and possibly a fix, if it is a bug).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by Maerlyn, this seems to be a known issue of PDO driver and, therefore, of Doctrine DBAL.

Without making use of the mapping abilities provided by Doctrine 2 ORM layer, I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11494408/1540486) answer as a possible workaround to DBAL limitations.